# Why are Global Load Balancer in GCP only External?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

Global Load Balancers have backend instances running in multiple regions. External LBs have source traffic from the internet. But, that does not rule out the use for internal global LB. Unfortunately, I haven't found any docs for the same. Why can't we have an internal global load balancer in GCP?

Comment: Not sure if someone here could answer that. IMHO that's something you should ask directly to Google in issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187245&template=0 and not in SO

Comment: Have you checked this [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal#three-tier_web_service_with_global_access_example)? you can enable global access to internal load balancer.

Comment: @Puteri Thanks for the suggestion, I have opened an issue for Google

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde The doc describes how to enable global access "to" internal LB. But global LB in itself should support backend instances running in multiple regions, not clients "from" multiple regions.

Comment: Please update your question to clarify. Google has many types of load balancers. Select the one that meets your design criteria.